When is it appropriate to redirect a question to Stack Overflow?
I was recently reviewing this question: 
How to watch for the transactions over blockchain via nodejs?
It has been voted to be closed with the reason being "off-topic because belongs on stackoverflow".  While I agree that stackoverflow may result in the OP getting a better answer (and sooner), I have a hard time agreeing that this question is off topic.  After all, our tour lists the following as on-topic criteria:

Problems with developing applications specific to the cryptocurrency domain

We tend to get a lot of questions here regarding specific libraries and languages, and they seem to be tolerated (if not upvoted very much).  This is certainly a place to find experts in this domain, even though we are not coding-specific.  Do we have any established criteria for determining whether a question should be reposted on SO, and therefore closed on Bitcoin SE?

The focus of the linked question appears to be about using a Bitcoin specific library to solve a Bitcoin specific issue. It seems likely that a Bitcoin library can be pointed out that solves the asker's problem and I'd vote on keeping it.
If however, there is no library that solves this problem, and this becomes a "how do I implement this feature" it would probably fit better on SO, although that observation would also only be made here.
